# Binomial sum with index as Arithmetic Progression

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Consider a binomial sum of form,
>
> $$ S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{n}{a_k}$$
> Where,
> $$ a_k  = a_o + (k-1) d$$ w/ $a_o \geq 0 $ $ d \geq 0$

An immediate simplification is that for terms with, $ a_k \geq n$ are zero. So, if there is a $j$ such that $n \in [a_j,a_{j+1} ]$ , then the sum's upper index turns to:

$$ S = \sum_{k=1}^{j} \binom{n}{a_k}$$

A brute force way to calculate would be to directly add them after that, but is there a simpler way to solve this?

The person who sent me this problem mentioned that I could use roots of unity to solve this.. but I'm not sure how that relates to here...

Answer (score 3):

The standard method to solve these involves the **roots of unity filter** (or finite Fourier analysis for the pretentious).

The idea is to look at the polynomial $f(x)=x^{d-a_0}(1+x)^n$. This has the property that the coefficient of $x^{dk}$ is $\binom{n}{a_0+dk}$. So if we could somehow extract only the coefficients of $x^{dk}$ and sum them, we would be done.

The trick is to consider $$\frac{f(1)+f(\omega)+\dots+f\left(\omega^{d-1}\right)}{d},$$ where $\omega=\exp(2i\pi/d)$ is the $d$-th root of unity. Can you see why this extracts only the coefficients of $x^{dk}$ in the sum?

---

To make this concrete, consider the following example:
$$\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{2021}{3k+1}.$$
Take the polynomial $f(x)=x^2(1+x)^{2021}$, so writing $\omega=\exp(2i\pi/3)$, the sum we want is
$$\frac{(1+1)^{2021}+\omega^2(1+\omega)^{2021}+\omega(1+\omega^2)^{2021}}{3}.$$
Now in general, at this point you'd just convert to polar form $1+\omega^m=re^{i\theta}$ and bash it out, but for $n=3$ you can take advantage of the neat trick that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ to make the calculation easier:
\begin{align*}
\frac{(1+1)^{2021}+\omega^2(1+\omega)^{2021}+\omega(1+\omega^2)^{2021}}{3} &= \frac{1}{3}\left[2^{2021}+\omega^2(-\omega^2)^{2021}+\omega(-\omega)^{2021}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left[2^{2021}-\omega^{4044}-\omega^{2022}\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left[2^{2021}-2\right].
\end{align*}

Comment: What is the significance of the factor $x^{d-a_0}$?

Comment: @newbie105 Well without it, the terms you want look like $\binom{n}{a_0+kd}x^{a_0+kd}$. You can probably concoct some root of unity expression to extract these, but much easier to remove that annoying $x^{a_0}$ the way I did

Comment: I tried your method in this [question](https://imgur.com/BOz09vg), but it gave me an incorrect result

Comment: Right -- try the method again with just $f(x)=(1+x)^{32}$ instead :)

Comment: It doesnt make a difference. The leading factor is $1$ for both the cases

Comment: There is this weird $3^{16}$ term in the answer. I have got no idea where it comes from

Comment: Should be fine: expression you get is $(2^{32}+(1+\omega)^{32}+(1+\omega^2)^{32}+(1+\omega^3)^{32}+(1+\omega^4)^{32}+(1+\omega^5)^{32})/6$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117956/discussion-between-newbie105-and-jlammy).

Comment: @jlammy in the definition of 'f', why did you make it $-a_o$..? I mean how do you know for sure a term of $a_o +dk$ must come in expansion of that poly

Comment: @Buraian as I explained in a comment above, without that leading factor, when you binomial expand, the terms you want look like $\binom{n}{a_0+kd}x^{a_0+kd}$. I want to make the power of $x$ associated with $\binom{n}{a_0+kd}$ a multiple of $d$, as this makes the root of unity trick easier.